# Installing Quantlib Python PyQL library: seems not to be able to find Boost

Tags: python, boost, quantlib

I am trying to install the Python PyQL library which wraps Quantlib but it seems to be failing to find some boost headers.

I already have the latest version of Quantlib (1.3) working and located in the /usr/local/lib directory, along with Boost 1.5:

```
xxx@LILJEN:/usr/local/lib$ ls
boost  boost_1_50_0  libQuantLib.a  libQuantLib.la  libQuantLib.so  libQuantLib.so.0  libQuantLib.so.0.0.0  python2.7  python3.3  QuantLib-1.3  QuantLib-SWIG-1.3  R  site_ruby
```

I have Cython 0.2 installed:

```
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("Cython").version
'0.20'
```

When I go into the pyql directory where I downloaded the package and do a make build command I get an issue with the Boost library, as otherwise it seems to be "Cythonizing" everthing properly. I note that that Github instructions said that I should "patch" Cython 0.16, but since I am already on 0.2 I assume this is not necessary. Here is what the build says:

```
xxx@LILJEN:~/Downloads/pyql$ sudo make build
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/extension.py:133: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'pyrex_directives'
  warnings.warn(msg)
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.time': quantlib/instruments/credit_default_swap.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.pricingengines': quantlib/instruments/credit_default_swap.pyx
missing cimport in module 'quantlib.pricingengines': quantlib/instruments/option.pyx
Compiling quantlib/quotes.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/interest_rate.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendar.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/schedule.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/date.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/daycounter.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/daycounters/actual_actual.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/daycounters/thirty360.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendars/germany.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendars/united_states.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendars/united_kingdom.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendars/null_calendar.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/time/calendars/jointcalendar.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/instruments/swap.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/credit.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/swap.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/bond.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/blackformula.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/engine.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/mcvanillaengine.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/vanilla.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/sim/simulate.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/processes/bates_process.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/processes/black_scholes_process.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/processes/heston_process.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/math/optimization.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/default_term_structure.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/credit/piecewise_default_curve.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/credit/default_probability_helpers.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/volatility/equityfx/black_vol_term_structure.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/yields/yield_term_structure.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/yields/zero_curve.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/yields/piecewise_yield_curve.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/yields/rate_helpers.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/termstructures/yields/flat_forward.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/models/equity/bates_model.pyx because it changed.
Compiling quantlib/models/equity/heston_model.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing quantlib/instruments/swap.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/interest_rate.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/math/optimization.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/models/equity/bates_model.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/models/equity/heston_model.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/blackformula.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/bond.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/credit.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/engine.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/swap.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/mcvanillaengine.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/pricingengines/vanilla/vanilla.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/processes/bates_process.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/processes/black_scholes_process.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/processes/heston_process.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/quotes.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/sim/simulate.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/credit/default_probability_helpers.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/credit/piecewise_default_curve.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/default_term_structure.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/volatility/equityfx/black_vol_term_structure.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/yields/flat_forward.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/yields/piecewise_yield_curve.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/yields/rate_helpers.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/yields/yield_term_structure.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/termstructures/yields/zero_curve.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendar.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendars/germany.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendars/jointcalendar.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendars/null_calendar.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendars/united_kingdom.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/calendars/united_states.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/date.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/daycounter.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/daycounters/actual_actual.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/daycounters/thirty360.pyx
Cythonizing quantlib/time/schedule.pyx
running build_ext
building 'quantlib.cashflow' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/quantlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I./cpp_layer -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c quantlib/cashflow.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/quantlib/cashflow.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
quantlib/cashflow.cpp:342:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
                                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the boost library, even though this is clearly installed and working since I compiled Quantlib from scratch successfully and the test suite works. Any hints as to where I might be getting something wrong?

It's Ubuntu 13.10 and the default installed Python 2.7. Essentially this is a newly installed system with all the latest libraries (except for Boost which I kept at 1.5).

Fwiw python setup.py install does not work either, but I have the regular SWIG Quantlib library working fine in Python.

---

ADDENDUM

I believe the "error" I have is that I closely followed [this excellent page](http://quantess.net/2012/09/26/quantlib-get-it-working-on-ubuntu/) on how to install Quantlib on Ubuntu. That page talks about Boost in the usr/local/lib directory, and I copied and pasted its commands. Quantlib compiled perfectly because the Boost directory was communicated via the export command as per the page, but pyql needed also to have this directory specified in setup.py. It is a matter of ensuring that the line under sys.platform = "linux2", specifying the INCLUDE_DIRS to usr/local/lib rather than the default usr/local/include. I write this addendum because I believe many users may also google search "install Quantlib Ubuntu" and find this page, therefore this problem may recur for a number of people.

Comment: Where are your Boost headers? Are they in /usr/local/include, or somewhere else?

Comment: I see them in /usr/local/lib. Well anyway there I see the directory boost_1_50_0, and under there I see a directory called boost. I assume these are the boost headers? You can see the contents of my /usr/local/lib folder at the top of my question.

Comment: Is there, for instance, a file `shared_ptr.hpp` inside /usr/local/lib/boost_1_50_0/boost? That's what the compiler is looking for.

Comment: Indeed there is: 

......xxx@LILJEN:/usr/local/lib/boost_1_50_0/boost$ ls sh*
......shared_array.hpp  shared_container_iterator.hpp  shared_ptr.hpp........

Could it be that I need to edit setup.py to allow it to find it? I am using the default setup.py found in the pyql github. It seems to have default locations for various operating systems, and for debian it seems to suggest that things should work unchanged, but perhaps I need to change these?

Comment: perhaps I should be relocating the place from where I am trying to build pyql? I am currently doing so from a directory called pyql under my home directory, whereas boost is in usr/local/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the command line that launches the compiler, you'll see

```
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I./cpp_layer -I/usr/include/python2.7
```

which are the flags that tell the compiler where to look for headers.  Your Boost headers aren't in any of those (which is strange: headers usually go somewhere in /usr/local/include. Did you copy them in /usr/local/lib yourself?) so the compiler can't find them.

You can either:

- move the boost directory in /usr/local/include (that would be the directory named "boost", not the one called "boost_1_50_0"), or
- pass an additional flag `-I/usr/local/lib/boost_1_50_0` to the compiler so that it can find them in their current location. The way to do this will depend on your setup.py script.

Comment: Success! The setup.py file had the INCLUDE_DIRS set to  /usr/local/include and the LIBRARY_DIRS set to usr/local/lib. Being fairly new to linux I thought if the LIBRARY_DIRS was correct that would somehow work. Editing setup.py to the correct directory sees the whole thing working and the test suite working. However, one more question: How do I include this new thing? import pyql or import PyQL doesn't see anything. That said I know it's working because sudo make test worked perfectly.

Comment: Ignore the last line from previous comment. All the examples are working properly. It imports as "quantlib" and is working perfectly. Was confused because that's how the SWIG version is also imported (perhaps with capital Q, I don't remember). All good and working perfectly.